# Include a js script inside of joomla index page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, joomla

My friend asked me to add a simple javascript to her page. Unfortunately it is built on joomla (which I have never used). I cannot find any place to include such a script. There are some empty indexes everywhere. Is there any way to do this? I just need to make the page scroll to some position after pressing a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add your script in this file:

> [sitename]/templates/[current_template]/**index.php**

You can find out the name of the current template in

- Go to Administration > Extensions > Template Manager (it will be starred, see screen below)
  [image]
  After that you shold click on template name link, and on other page click *Edit main page template* for editing **index.php** (it depends from template).
- The second way to find out the template name it's browser DevTools, see screen below. [image]

Also you can edit template file via FTP + your text editor.

**UPDATE:** For **Jm internet** theme main template file is here:

> [template_root]/tpl/**default.php**

Also main template layout can loads from these files: *content-left-right.php*, *left-right-content.php* etc. It depends from selected options in template settings.

Comment: This template index.php looks strange. It contains only this code: `defined('_JEXEC') or die;

if (!defined('JMF_EXEC')) {
 throw new Exception(JText::_('TPL_JMTEMPLATE_MISSING_JFM'));
}

include_once(JMF_TPL_PATH.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'lib'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'jm_template.php');

$jmtpl = new JMTemplate($this);
$jmtpl->renderScheme('default');` Damn... no `html`, `body` etc??

Comment: Can you provide link to your theme?

Comment: It is called "jm internet" theme

Comment: Ok, try to open this file: [current_template]/tpl/default.php 
Do you see any html-tags?

Comment: Yes, there is just html tag and milions of objective php code, included modules etc. Damn this will be difficult :D Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your template, the path may vary depending on the framework
 or structure of your template, most commonly the main file is called **index.php**.

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

// In this example the js file is called main.js inside js folder
$doc->addScript('/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/main.js', 'text/javascript’);
```

Some templates also include an option to add your custom files or code directly
in your template configuration, check out the options of your template.

Regards.